# How to select multiple files in a folder in internal storage using Storage Access Framework in android?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-file, storage-access-framework, android-storage

I want to retrieve all files that are images or videos in a specific folder in internal storage. I want to fetch them in my application using Storage Access Framework. Is there any way to do this? please guide me with some code example on how can I do this.

Comment: It all starts with a saf uri for that folder. Now do you have such an uri?

Comment: No I dont how can I have that uri?

Comment: You have to let the user select the folder with ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE.